# VS Team Services git Dependency Build

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am new to Team Services (web based) build process. Previously I asked a different question for a solution with using TF for version control. Thanks to a great individual that problem was solved. I am now experimenting with git for version control and ran into a similar situation.

I have a Solution 1 with Project A and B where B is dependent on A (common code). Project A is under a different Solution 2 but was added to Solution 1 via "Add...Existing Project". Both solutions and projects are under different git repo. I use submodule for Project B to pull in Project A and that part works. However, Project A is pulled in under "d:\a\1\s\ProjectA" and 
when the build agent attempts to build Project B, it is looking at "d:\a\1\s\ProjectB....\ProjectA\" for the dependency. How do I change this part to tell the build agent the location of Project A? Or how can I tell the submodule to pull Project A to "d:\a\1\s\ProjectB....\ProjectA\"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you added ProjectA as submodule for the ProjectB, so you should add dependent for ProjectB by selecting ProjectA in submodule (not solution 2). So you should remove the projectA you added, and then use Add -> Existing Project -> select projectA from submodule -> OK.

Then commit/push changes to VSTS git repo. And build your ProjectB, it should find the dependent in the submodule path.

Or if you want the submodule located in `root/ProjectB/.../ProjectA`, in your local repo, you should go to the directory `root/ProjectB/...`, and use `git submodule add <URL for the repo including ProjectA>`. Then the submodule will located in `root/ProjectB/.../ProjectA`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I was using the 2nd route anyway. Previously I was tripped up twice by when I loaded the submodule at different folder structure (up in the root, and then 1 level above the solution file). I loaded the submodule at the Project B level at my local repo and it worked, but not before I had to manually change .gitmodules. Questions - why was the path in the .gitmodules a relative path (I had to change it to a local path to make it work), and why where there 2 entries in it? One was [Project A], the other is [Project B/ProjectA].

Comment: `.gitmodules` use the relative path so that git will find it easily which directory is submodule. Actually there is only one entry which was the path you selected for the reference you added (It seems you added the reference by selecting `ProjectB/.../ProjectA`), for `projectA/`, it just the submodule you added in projectB, the build will only find the reference you specified in `ProjectB/.../ProjectA`.